# (Tortoise)SVN: Merging large revision errors out with HTTP error

Tags: svn, merge

Over the past month, my team and I rewrote one of my company's largest code bases. This involved restructuring of the subdirectories, which is where the problem is coming.

I am at the stage where we are merging our feature branch back into the trunk, and I am getting stuck merging the revision where we re-structured our folders. Something like 200 MB of stuff got moved around. When trying to merge that specific revision, I get "ra_serf: The server sent a truncated HTTP response body"

From what I understand, fixing it involves adjusting timeouts on our SVN server, which I have no control over. So what now? What are my other options for merging the branch back into the trunk? Can I nuke the whole trunk directory, copy the branch on top of it, and manually edit the mergeinfo?

Answer (score 1):

- Fire on officio discrepancy company's IT-department
- Get local copy of repository (`svnrdump`|`svnadmin dump` + `svnadmin load`), perform merge in WC of *this* repository (with UUID unchanged from original)
- relocate after successful merge WC to remote repository
- Commit mergeset into correct repository
- Hire new persons into IT-department